# What is the correct way to propogate changes in connected DynamoDB tables

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

I'm a beginner in Serverless and dynamoDB. My use case consists of two tables Trips and Routes. 
Trips table consists of these parameters `{id, Route, Cost, Distance, Time}`. Routes table consists of these parameters {quantity, Rate, From, To }.

Cost param in the Trips table is calculated by `quantity * Rate` params from the routes table. Every time a trip is created/edited I fetch the value from the table and store the new value as `Cost` param of trips table.

The issue arises when someone changes the `quantity` or `rate` parameter in the Routes table, how do I propogate this change to Trips table? Currently I'm updating the `Cost` Parameter everytime someone updates Routes, is there a more efficient way?

Comment: DynamoDB is `NoSQL` and it can store json type within the `Trips` table, which will save cost of DynamoDB usage as well. So you can store the full info of routes in the `Route` filed of `Trips` table. And then Cost can be calculated dynamically.

Comment: Also please be aware of that `aws` suggests to use as less table as you can.

Comment: @Perfect There are different kinds of routes for which a trip can be created and a user can CRUD new routes as well hence a different table for that. Also even if i store the whole field value of the route(from Routes table) in the route field of trips, how would that propogate a change made in the route from Routes table to the route field in Trips table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamodb streams. Any change in the route table can be captured in these streams and processed to update the corresponding object in your Trips table. DynamoDB does not support aggregations unfortunately otherwise the cost field could have been computed while querying the object which would have been a lot easier.